# Typescript data type questions

Tags: typescript

I am not familiar with typescript.
Could someone please explain what data type of typescript field selectedNames below is.

```
class Doit { private selectedNames : { [level: number] : {[name: string]: boolean} } = {}; }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`selectedNames` has an object type. It has a numeric index signature, whose type for convenience let's call it `T`. In other words, `selectedNames` has properties with numeric property names and `T` property types.

And `T` is also an object type. `T` has a string index signature, whose type is `boolean`. In other words, `T` has properties with string property names and `boolean` property types.

And the `= {}` is an initializer that assigns an empty object to the `selectedNames` property of class `Doit`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`[level: number] : {[name: string]: boolean}` is the type. It describes the dictionary pattern

`[level : number]` is the key.
`{[name: string]: boolean}` are the values, 
in this case another dictionary string to bool.

compare http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-array-types